# "InvalidRequestError: Session is already flushing" has been occurred in before_flush hook

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to execute validation over multiple models. Below document says that can access attributes freely via `Session.dirty` in `before_flush`.
But, my code raise `Session is already flushing` in `before_flush`.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/session_events.html

After several tries, I found that `lazy='dynamic'` is one of reasons but lazy option is necessary for other view.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

#### Definition of model and listener

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql://dummy:dummy@127.0.0.1/dummy')
Base = declarative_base()


class Action(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'actions'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    topic_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('topics.id'))
    topic = relationship('Topic', back_populates='actions')


class Topic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'topics'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    actions = relationship('Action', back_populates='topic', lazy='dynamic')


Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


@event.listens_for(Session, 'before_flush')
def validate_before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    for instance in session.dirty:
        print(instance)          # no problem(<__main__.Topic object at 0x7fa68165ecf8>)
        print(instance.name)     # no problem(modified)
        print(instance.actions)  # raise InvalidRequestError: Session is already flushing
```

#### Modify model and raise error

```
session = Session()
topic = session.query(Topic).get(1)
topic.name = 'modified'
session.commit()    # Execute before_flush and raise InvalidRequestError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have autoflush on, then SQLAlchemy will try to flush before querying anything from the database (e.g. loading a relationship), but flushing is not supported while the session is already flushing (e.g. in a `before_flush` hook), so you end up with this error. Try turning off autoflush:

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False)
```

Note that turning off autoflush may (albeit rarely) break your app, if your app is written to depend on that behavior. Make sure you understand the implications of turning it off.

Comment: Thanks! It works in my example code. Our production code has some problem as univerio says, I disable autoflush while hook by `session.no_autoflush` and works.